# I don't want to resize dialog by webview in android

Tags: android, webview, dialog, android-alertdialog

In app, I used the webview, I had some problem, I want to pretty loading webview
The problem is that The dialog is be resize by webview every second
I want to fit the dialog box size
The webview completely load page after appear the dialogbox

I was try the code

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder;
Dialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);


    WebView wv = new WebView(this);

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl("http:\\www.google.com");
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                            @Override
                            public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {

                                return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                                dialog.setContentView(view);

                            }


                            @Override
                            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String
                                    url) {
                                view.loadUrl(url);
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
    );
    dialog = builder.setView(new View(this)).create();

    dialog.show();


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use these two lines

```
dialog = builder.setView(new View(this)).create();
dialog.show();
```

also use this as layout parameters to dialog if you want or set them to webview.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
```

after

```
WebView wv = new WebView(this);
```

Comment: the same result, I don't want to see resizing dialog by webview. I want to en frame the lockup dialog